# How to share Vue Component Prop Definition in TypeScript throght Vue.extend()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Please see this minimum example

If I write my props directly inside the component, everything is fine

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    colorType: {
      default: "primary" as const,
      type: String as PropType<"primary" | "secondary" | "other">,
      validator: (value) => ["primary", "secondary", "other"].includes(value),
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

However, if I extract the props definition outside, it will break types

[image]

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from "vue";

const colorType = {
  default: "primary" as const,
  type: String as PropType<"primary" | "secondary" | "other">,
  validator: (value) => ["primary", "secondary", "other"].includes(value),
};

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    colorType,
  },
});
</script>
```

How can I share those prop type definition accross Vue components without breaking TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const colorType = {
    default: 'primary' as const,
    type: String,
    validator: (value) => ['primary', 'secondary', 'other'].includes(value),
} as PropValidator<'primary' | 'secondary' | 'other'>;
```

I think this works

Comment: Note: `import { PropValidator } from 'vue/types/options';`

Comment: Thank you! That's insane TypeScript skills right there.